# Getting a MATLAB Link Budget Analysis file from the MATLAB website

Tags: matlab

I am really new to MATLAB but I wanted to try this code for an upcoming personal project but I'm unable to download this project? I tried the MATLAB command to download the files but all it seems to do is give me an empty file. Downloading the reference files at the bottom seems to do nothing? Do you know where I'm going wrong?

Link: https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/examples/link-budget-analysis.html

Answer (score 0):

The example is part of the Communications Toolbox. When you have this toolbox insatlled, `edit LinkBudgetAnalysisExample` will open that file. When you use edit and a file ist not present, it will ask you if it should create an empty file.

I guess you don't have the toolbox licensed and installed.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I did have the toolboxes and installed and I tried the edit LinkBudgetAnalysisExample but all it did was create an empty file.

Comment: What does `ver;which -all LinkBudgetAnalysisExample` return? Please add this information to your question, probably won't be readable in the comment.